# Add a custom field to my custom post type and then get posts which are before the given date in the custom field

Tags: custom-field

Hi all "Want to do it without plugin"

Firstly how can I create a custom field in my custom post type where I can get the date

```
// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( '',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Archive' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Archive'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}

// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

I want to fetch the posts which has  date in "Custom post" before the current date.
Example -> If in the custom field I entered 2021-12-25 and it's before the current date then the post should be fetched and after the current date crossed 2021-12-25 post should not be fetched.

Comment: This logic belongs to a plugin. You should not put it into the theme code, so a plugin is your only option.

Comment: Thank you for your time are you saying about the custom field or fetching the post according to the field?